# Centos 7 KVM cifs mount issues

Tags: linux, centos, qemu, linux-kvm, cifs

I am having a issue with Centos changing my KVM images folder from the default to a Cifs Shared folder. Any time I try it, it returns a error like so:

```
[root@localhost Centos_Atomic]# systemctl status libvirtd -l
Nov 27 22:44:30 localhost.localdomain libvirtd[1365]: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2015-11-28T04:44:30.175326Z qemu-kvm: -drive file=/var/lib/libvirt/images/Centos_Atomic/Centos_Atomic.qcow2,if=none,id=drive-ide0-0-0,format=qcow2: could not open disk image /var/lib/libvirt/images/Centos_Atomic/Centos_Atomic.qcow2: Could not open file: Permission denied
```

I have already tried messing with the Selinux permission which are currently in permission mode and did `setsebool -P virt_use_nfs 1`. I have created symbolic links in the default folder and pointed them to my share. I have changed the allowed users and group in `etc/libvirt/qemu.conf` to both root. I have also added the root user to both the kvm and qemu groups.

I was able to start images in the default folder and I have been able to get this work in Ubuntu before but I am not sure why it's a issue with Centos.

How do i change my KVM images folder from the default to a Cifs Shared folder in Centos?